# Log HAProxy custom header

Tags: logging, redhat, haproxy

I'm looking to get HAProxy to both set a custom header **and** log it.

Below is a paired down example of my haproxy.cfg (I've left out some SSL details and multiple backends that I believe are not relevant to my problem)

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1 local0 debug

defaults
    log global
    stats enable
    option httplog


frontend httpFrontendi
    mode http
    bind *:80    
    http-request add-header Foo Bar
    capture request header Foo len 64
    log-format Foo\ %[capture.req.hdr(0)]\ %hr\ %hrl\ %hs\ %hsl  

    default_backend backend_api
    redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }


backend backend_api
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    option httpchk HEAD /api/test_db HTTP/1.0
    server backend_api1 ip:80 check inter 5s rise 2 fall 3
```

I call the proxy with:

```
curl 127.0.0.1
```

I was then expecting to see the custom header in the log, but it does not show:

```
Nov 10 17:49:36 localhost haproxy[22355]: Foo - {} -
```

The hardcoded "Foo" appears, so the `log-format` command is clearly working. But everything else renders as empty... are custom headers set after logging? How can one log a custom header?

I am new to HAProxy so I think this may be some understanding I'm missing.

(I start HAProxy with cmd `sudo haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg` and observe log with `sudo tail -f /var/log/haproxy/haproxy.log`. This is on HA-Proxy version 1.6.2)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this:

```
http-request add-header Foo Bar
#capture request header Foo len 64
http-request capture req.hdr(Foo) len 64
log-format Foo\ %[capture.req.hdr(0)]\ %hr\ %hrl\ %hs\ %hsl
```

Note that `capture` get executed before `http-request`, so you cannot log Foo.

Comment: You don't need to change log-format, the header is inserted on the log as the documentation of `http-request capture` points `...It will then automatically appear in the logs..`